# Exploring Polygon Drawing in Hyperbolic Space with Integer Factor Angles: Seeking Simpler or Standard Methods

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, coxeter-groups

I am currently attempting to draw polygons in hyperbolic space with angles that are integer multiples of pi, i.e., $\pi / k$ for k an integer. I am particularly interested in determining the vertex positions of such polygons, especially in the context of the Upper Half Plane (UHP) or the Poincaré Disk model. While I have come across a generalization of the second hyperbolic law of cosines to polygons by Glushchenko et al. (2020), which deals with the analytical calculation of multi-beam interference of coherent light, I am curious if there are simpler or more standard approaches commonly used in the community for this purpose. Any guidance or references would be greatly appreciated.

** I know that there is [a discussion for the case of hyperbolic triangles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401860/vertices-of-hyperbolic-triangle-with-given-angles) so I googled further ended up finding Glushchenko et al. (2020).

### Reference

Glushchenko et al. (2020):
[Glushchenko, Alexandra, Alexander Glushchenko, and Eugenia Glushchenko. "Generalization of the Cosines Theorem to Polygons and Its Application to the Analytical Calculation of Multi-Beam Interference of Coherent Radiation of Light with an Arbitrary Phase Distribution." European Journal of Physics Education 11.3 (2020): 38-46.](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/EJ1300058.pdf)